# Get permutations of each item available in list

Tags: java, arraylist, permutation

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("MP");
list.add("Maharastra");
list.add("Karnataka");
```

My requirement is to get all the possible permutation from above list.

Expected Output as list is

```
[MP:Maharastra, MP:Karnataka, Maharastra:MP, Maharastra:Karnataka, Karnataka:MP, Karnataka:Maharastra]
```

Currently I added only three items in list but this list can hold any number of items.

Comment: You have requirements - OK; what have you done so far? what did you try? where exactly you're stuck at? you shouldn't be posting your homework tasks expecting others to solve them.

Comment: A permutation would have three elements in your case e.g. `Maharastra:MP:Karnataka`. Your expected output shows something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested loop to pair each element with every other element in the `List` except itself.

```java
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++){
        if(i != j){
            result.add(list.get(i) + ":" + list.get(j));
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

With Java 8 streams, it's much simpler:

```
List<String> result = list.stream().flatMap(s -> list.stream().filter(t -> (Objects.nonNull(t)
 && !t.equalsIgnoreCase(s))).map(t -> s.concat(":").concat(t))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```